# Small images (<4MB) in MongoDB, should I use gridFS?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, multer, gridfs, multer-gridfs-storage

Rather simple question and request here, but haven't been able to find a firm answer yet. I am new to multer, Node, and MongoDB and it's been a bigger struggle than I expected.

I want to store small JPEGs in MongoDB, probably not more 4 MB each. I understand that BSON can be up to < 16 MB, and if larger, must be handled by gridfs.

These images would just be profile photos for each _id I have in a collection. So far, I have been able to upload files locally using just multer. Now I am trying to figure out how to get these images in MongoDB and in the correct way.

Do I need gridfs for such small images? What would be my best plan to execute this?

I am picturing doing an upsert of the file to the database but wonder if this will just upload the filename and not the image itself? How would I change my "schema" to accommodate this? If you have an idea of how to change my upsert below (vs going into gridFS), that would be ideal. Here is the code.

Database update:

```
const updatePlace = async (place) => {
  const database = await connect();
  return database.collection('place').findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: new ObjectID(place._id) },
    {
      $set: {
        name: place.name,
        category: place.category,
        city: place.city,
        state: place.state,
        country: place.country,
        image: { filename: place.image, mime: 'image/jpeg' },
      },
    },
    { upsert: true, returnOriginal: false }
  );
};
```

The storage and upload:

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './public/uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '_' + file.originalname);
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

Mongo DB item as it is now:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fbc37c4fc13ae680b00001e"
  },
  "name": "Petronas Towers",
  "category": "activity",
  "city": "Kuala Lumpur",
  "state": "Kuala Lumpur",
  "country": "Malaysia",
  "image": {
    "filename": "petronas.jpg",
    "mime": "image/jpeg"
  }
}
```

Comment: I personally would store the images in a cloud storage (S3 is a popular choice). Not only this improves performance of your database, but you also can benefit from browser's caching and parallel asset loading. Your app just renders an S3 URL, and then browser handles the rest.

Comment: If someone gave you a satisfying answer to your question, please mark them as accepted answer :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridFS is not a bad choice. You get:

- Automatic index creation by the driver, hence efficient retrieval
- Flexibility if your images grow beyond 16 mb
- Separate metadata and content storage

You can alternatively use the binary type and store image data directly in fields. This will have less overhead but:

- You should either still store metadata separate for content or benchmark that solution vs one where the content is inline in the documents (because skipping over content bytes can be slow when you just need metadata)
- You would need to handle metadata yourself

Comment: Thanks, D. SM. I haven't yet found a GridFS tutorial so far that I have been able to follow. I am not seeing in any of those tutorials how the image uploaded is tied to a particular record and how I could find({}) it later on with database queries. I feel GridFS is the best, but I am pressed for time. 

With Grid FS, I was thinking the images would be put in the db with a findOneAndUpdate() with upsert: true, I don't see how it could be done any other way. 

I hope I explained that well. Do you have any particular tutorial you could direct me to that is best for newbies?

Comment: For Ruby see https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-gridfs/.

Comment: For what I am doing, I am working with node.js / express / handlebars / oboe. Will this still be a help?

Answer (score 1):

You are encouraged to save files that are small in size (less than 16
MB) to MongoDB as data of the Buffer type (i.e. BSON binary type). BSON binary type is used to store any kind of binary data. BSON binary type corresponds to the RDBMS BLOB type, and it’s the basis for two kinds of binary object storage provided by MongoDB (the other being GridFS). GridFS is a specification in MongoDB that makes possible storing large files (like videos, large audio files and images) in MongoDB by dividing a given file into several chunks, which in turn gives us the ability to fetch and load only parts of the file as required, rather than retrieving the whole file.

It is recommended that you do not use GridFS if all the files you need to store are less than 16 MB in size. If this is the case, and you still want to take advantage of using MongoDB, simply store the file directly in a normal MongoDB document. The maximum size of a BSON document is 16 MB, so if all your files are smaller, using GridFS is a waste of resources.

But for educational purposes, there is nothing wrong if you use GridFS for files smaller than 16MB, the above applies only to production level projects.